# Route не рендерит компонент. У Двух компонентов одинаковый путь но Route рендерит только один компонент

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Есть два компонента и нужно чтобы они оба рендерились по одному пути.
Компонент `PostWrap` будет меняться а компонент `People` будет меняться редко. Вот код

```
import React from 'react';
import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Header from './components/header';
import MyProfile from './containers/profile';
import PostsWrap from './containers/posts';
import People from './containers/people';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header />
      <div className="container all-center container-around">
        <MyProfile />
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={PostsWrap}/>
          <Route exact path="/" component={People}/>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас стоит атрибут **exact** а он рендерит только первый подходящий компонент (в вашем случае это компонент `PostsWrap`) для маршрута `"/"`.

Можно решить это так:

```
<Route exact path='/' render={props =>
  <>
    <PostsWrap />
    <People />
  </>
} />
```

атрибут **render** в `Route` — функция которая должна вернуть элемент React. Будет вызвана когда удовлетворится сопоставление в `path` .

И отрендерит сразу два компонента `PostsWrap` и `People`